# Output formated table with fprintf

Tags: c, formatting, printf

Is there any easy way to format that table?

I am reading a txt file using a structure. But when printing it on the screen it not organised.

```
fprintf(stdout,"%d.\t'%s'\t%d\t%d\t%d\n",read.serial,read.name,read.roll,read.day1,read.day2);
```

[image: Output]

I want this kind of output

```
No.  Name                              ID        #1 #2
1.  Sajjad Kashem                   1330273      0  1 
2.  Hafizul Karim                   1420595      1  1 
3.  Afsana Rahman                   1430458      1  1 
4.  Md. Yousuf Hosain               1510295      0  0 
5.  Md. Farhanuzzaman Reza Famous   1510303      1  0 
6.  Md. Minul Islam Talukdar        1510678      0  1
```

Comment: Please show a [mre] of the code you mention. Also please explain what you actual problem is. The obvious way is to determine the desired width of each column and then pad each entry accordingly. Where on that method do you get stuck?

Comment: What do you mean by "when I am printing it on screen it not organised better"? Not better than what? What do expect/hope to happen? Show that, by mocking it manually please.

Comment: Instead of using `\t`, you can specify a fixed width for the fields, like this: `%10d`, which would add padding in front of the integer, such that the total width is 10 characters. It is also possible to specify a width dynamically: `%*d` in which case you'll have to supply an additional integer argument specifying the desired width

Comment: @Yunnosch I edited my post you may now understand what I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use formated specifier like for instance `%20s` will use 20 charaters regardless if the size of the string is lesser, this will be aligned right, to align left you can use `%-20s`:

[Live demo](https://repl.it/@anastaciu/MammothOvercookedWireframe)

```
fprintf(stdout,"%-10s%-20s%10s%10s%10s\n\n", "No.", "Name", "ID", "#1", "#2");
fprintf(stdout,"%-10d%-20s%10d%10d%10d\n", 1, "random_name", 123456, 2, 5);
fprintf(stdout,"%-10d%-20s%10d%10d%10d\n", 2, "other_random_name", 1223, 2, 5);
fprintf(stdout,"%-10d%-20s%10d%10d%10d\n", 1, "yet_another_name", 3456980, 2, 5);
```

Will output:

```
No.       Name                        ID        #1        #2

1         random_name             123456         2         5
2         other_random_name         1223         2         5
3         yet_another_name       3456980         2         5
```